# When is the edited link shown on posts?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list, grace-period

I edited some of the answers and questions posted by myself. Sometimes an "edited" link is displayed but sometimes not.

If "edited" is not shown then I cannot see the revision history.

Please let me know what is the process to show "edited" link on post.

[image: see red box in image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were the last person who edited a post, you have a 5-minute grace period for which you can continue making additional edits without creating an extra "revision" in the history.

So, if it's your post and edit it within 5 minutes of posting it, no revision history link will appear because there are no other revisions to show.

Note that if someone else edits the post within your 5-minute grace period, additional edits you make will now count as a new revision.

Comment: If i post the answer and after one minute someone else post new answer. Now again I edit my answer after 2 minutes before completing 5 minutes grace period. Will I see the "edited" link or not?

Comment: No, as long as no one has edited your post, you still have a 5-minute grace period to make invisible edits.

Comment: I am asking if someone else post the new answer between my editing (not edited my answer). Then also no "edited" link will be visible for all editing done in five minutes grace period from the time when post was initially posted.

Comment: No, answers are **not** edits, so it does not affect your grace period. If they answer while you're editing, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: thanks a lot. This information will help me to respond better for the questions.

Answer (score 3):

That's because, after every edit, there is a five minute "grace period". In this period, if *you* make an edit, a new revision is not created--instead, the edits are made to the last revision itself. If you make such an edit on a new post of yours, the edit is made to the first revision and thus there is no "edited X ago" link.

To access the revision history{*} for posts with a single revision, just use this URL: `http://<site>/posts/<post id>/revisions`. To get the post id, use the 'link' button on a post and copy the *first* number in the URL.

<sup>*Note that they will still show one revision, in the revision history itself, but this is useful for fetching the source/etc of locked posts.</sup>